# Obtain list of occurring field values in report footer - ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to obtain a list of the different field values within an SSRS Report, and then display the result set on the page header.

See link below for an example.

I know that usually this would be completed simply with groups but the user does not want the Tasks split out.

Thanks

Example Report:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the unique values into a single cell, you will need to utilize the code behind functionality in SSRS.

1. Click on the background of your report and go to report properties -> Code.  Paste this function into the window:

   Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
   System.Array.Sort(items)
   Dim k As Integer = 0
   For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
   If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
   Continue For
   End If
   items(k) = items(i)
   k += 1
   Next
   Dim unique As String = New [String](k - 1) {}
   System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
   Return unique
   End Function
2. In the expression in your table where you want the unique values list, insert this expression:

   =Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(1,1, Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet1")), ",")

"Fields!ID.Value" is a reference to the field in your dataset that you want unique values from.

"DataSet1" is the name of the dataset that your field is located in.

What happens is that at runtime, the entire set of values from your query column are passed to the VB function which uses returns an array of unique values.  The expression in the report Joins the unique array values back together with a comma deliminator.